# How to add multiple sys args in Spyder python

Tags: python, command-line, arguments, spyder

I am using spyder and python 3.7. Due to various restrictions on my role I can only use sys arguments by adding them in run >> configuration per file. This works perfectly if I'm only passing one argument. When I add multiple, they are read as one. I've tried separating with , (comma), ;semicolon,single and double quotes, and as a list []. None of these work. Is there a specific way to pass a list of arguments rather than just one? I've looked all over but no solutions so far on this. Is this a bug? Or is there a straightforward fix?

Again, I'm looking to add a list of arguments by using the navigation menu run >> configuration per file, and adding multiple arguments in the text box.

Answer (score 0):

(*Spyder maintainer here*) You need to enter different arguments in `Run > Configuration per file` separated by `-` or `--`, for example

`-x 10 --start 20`

Comment: Thanks so much for responding, but his did not work. They are separated by spaces. Unusual, but this is the solution that works. Each space marks a new argument. :) Just adding this comment here for anyone who also has this issue.